# SQL Server : extracting the Midddle Characters without CHARINDEX

Tags: sql, sql-server

To start, I have seen the `CHARINDEX` results on here but none of them seem to be working  for my case.  The reasons are either a, `CHARINDEX` can't help me, or b, I am not understanding how `CHARINDEX` works. That being said, I would like to ask my question here in hopes that I can get some clarification on both how to solve my issue and `CHARINDEX` if that so happens to be the way this question is answered.

The variable that I am trying to extract from has varying length.  However, two things are always constant.

1. There is always a '/' as the 16th character in the string
2. The last character in the string is always '0' OR '1'

What I am trying to do is extract the name from between '/' and '0' or '1'.  In short, I want to chop off the first 16 characters and the last character of every string.  So far, this is what I have:

```
SELECT 
    SUBSTRING([string_name], 17, LEN([string_name]) - 1) AS 'username'
FROM
    [table_name]
```

The results I get still contain the 0 OR 1 at the end. What I need to do is somehow remove that 0 from the string. It is important to note that the number of characters between '/' and '0' are always different.

Current results:

```
gordon0
grant0
greg0
guy1
hanying0
```

Desired results:

```
gordon
grant
greg
guy
hanying
```

Any advice here would be wonderful.

Please let me know if you need any additional information from me. If possible, would like to maintain using either `SUBSTRING`, `LEFT` or `RIGHT`.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adjusting the length would seem to address your problem:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING([string_name], 17, LEN([string_name])-17) AS username
FROM [table_name]
```

Comment: Wow, ok! It sure did.  Can you help me understand why you chose -17?

Comment: @Chris . . . Primarily because it works.  To get the full length of the string you would us `- 16` -- one less than the "17" where you are starting (the difference of "1" is due to starting the string counting at 1 rather than 0).  To lop off the final character, you want `- 16 - 1`, hence `- 17`.

Comment: Ha! That I understand.  Appreciate the assistance.